# SSLStrip redirects too many times

Tags: tls, sslstrip

I am attempting to use SSLStrip on a website which has HSTS disabled, I specifically type the website URL with `http://` and it refuses to load in Safari, Chrome and a random chinese browser because of too many redirects.

I have tried this with two victims: Safari on an iPhone running iOS 11.1 and on an Android Phone running Nougat. In both instances, I am unable to access the website. I have checked that the setup is working as I am able to see encrypted POST requests in my `sslstrip.log` file.

Here are the requests and responses from `http://my.mit.edu` for instance:

Request: 
`Host: my.mit.edu
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1`

Response:
`Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: Keep-Alive
Location: http://my.mit.edu
Server: BigIP`

**20 identical requests and responses are made.**

This prompts firefox to give this error:

`Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.`

*I think it is also important to point out that I am facing this only on this domain and sslstrip is actually working fine on my [personal website](https://palashtanejapro.github.io) .*

Comment: This is not a general problem with sslstrip. I think you need to provide more information about the problem so that one can see what is actually going on. Useful would be to to see the actual requests  (especially URL) and responses (especially status code and Location header) between client and sslstrip.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich added the suggested details, please see if you can help me now :)

Comment: The question is still closed so I can not add an answer. But the problem is essentially an incomplete URL in the location header of the site (missing path) and the inability of the original sslstrip to deal with this. You might take a fixed version from https://github.com/noxxi/sslstrip which works around this problem.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks, it worked with your fix. If you could un-lock this question then I'd be happy to give you the accepted answer. I think this fix can be useful for people who face a similar problem with sslstrip.

Comment: I cannot reopen the question alone the same that I cannot close it alone. But there are several votes (including mine) already to reopen the question and currently only one more is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem is the server sending an unexpected (and invalid) URL in the Location header:

```
Location: http://my.mit.edu
```

This URL does not include a path, i.e. instead of being `http://host/` it is only `http://host`. Browsers implicitly work around this problem but sslstrip did not expect it. This results in using `http://host` (without path) as they key in its internal set where it looks up when to use HTTPS on the server side. The URL it gets from the request is instead `http://host/` (with path) and thus the lookup fails and it does not use HTTPS to the server. This causes the server to again issue a redirect response to HTTPS which shows the same wrong URL etc - resulting in the endless redirect you see.

This is not a major issue in in my opinion since  sslstrip was primarily designed as proof of concept to demonstrate a problem instead of being an attack tool. But anyway, the problem can be easily fixed with [this patch](https://github.com/noxxi/sslstrip/commit/575f886e3cf199416b6c91f2c2722594ef807aff).